# supplying javadoc in "class only" jar file

Tags: java, javadoc

I am distributing jar file for client as an API jar. I DON'T want them to see my source code (and say 'your code sucks'), but I want them to be able to see the docs (comments /** */ ?).

Am I right that I must supply a separate doc.jar file as well as the "class only" distribution jar file?

Is there anyway to **1. combine them together** and **2. let eclipse automatically found the docs** without setting the doc location manually?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How about improving your code?

Comment: well, 'my code sucks' is the joke, not the point. I'm kinda embarrasing (how come the above comment got 6 points? am I really that bad at making jokes? em)

Comment: Why are you deliberately making it harder for your clients to debug? Full source code is _extremely_ useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run Javadoc and create a separate .zip file of it.

Comment: so no other way to put them together and save user from "click an specifying the doc jar"?

Comment: @Gary X You don't want them together. The developers need the Javadoc. They then have to ship their product with your jar file to their customers, but their customers don't need the Javadoc in most cases. You can obviously make the Javadoc a jar file instead of a .zip if that's better for the developers.